# complex mysql constraints over foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraints

It seems rational to me to stop users or bad codes from inserting invalid data, but I don't remember to see this anywhere!

Consider the following tables
[image]

- How I can make sure an order is always referencing an address that is created by the same user?
- Is this kind of constraint usual and recommended? I mean, Do I even have to care about it in the design?

Comment: A user can insert multiple addresses?

Comment: @Sougata, yup, just an exmaple! but let's consider you can have orders delivered to your workplace or home or ....

Comment: Complex 'business logic' should be encoded in the layer of code between the user and the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since I would not expect a user to be able to place an order without a valid address, therefore I would simply remove the separate FK to the user table, and use the combined user id - address id fields from the address table as a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE orders AS (
   --[COLUMN DEFINITIONS]
   address_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
   user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_usr_addr FOREIGN KEY (user_id, address_id)
                        REFERENCES address(user_id, id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If an order is incomplete and does not have an address yet, then this should not be an issue for a multi column foreign key, since according to mysql documentation on [using foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> The MATCH clause in the SQL standard controls how NULL values in a
>   composite (multiple-column) foreign key are handled when comparing to
>   a primary key. MySQL essentially implements the semantics defined by
>   MATCH SIMPLE, which permit a foreign key to be all or partially NULL.
>   In that case, the (child table) row containing such a foreign key is
>   permitted to be inserted, and does not match any row in the referenced
>   (parent) table. It is possible to implement other semantics using
>   triggers.

Comment: nice suggestion! thanks, but I have incomplete orders where an address is not set yet, and what happens if a user decides to remove one of his addresses anytime?

Comment: An order should not be changed once it has been completed. So, if the user wants to change or delete an address that is already in a completed order, then you have to create a new address record or mark an address as deleted in yor address table, but do not actually delete the address. The other solution is not to use address as a foreign key, but copy its contents into the order. In this case will not even have a foreign key to the address table. You can use triggers for this scenario to enforce data integrity.

Comment: As for the incomplete orders without address: if you define the address id as nullable in orders, then I belive mysql will let you create an order where only user id is set, but the address is left as null.

Comment: See updated answer for more details on missing address.